# How to use text.js instead of default ejs in yeoman backbone generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/index.html) with backbone generator for front-end automation of my application.

My problem with yeoman backbone generator is when I create a backbone view with yo (`yo backbone:view myView`) It creates a `myView.ejs` template. I want it to be `myView.html`. I kind of got used to [text.js](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for my backbone templates.

How can I change the default template engine used by [yeoman backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) to text.js?

Answer (score 0):

We are sorry that yeoman now doesn't support text.js. By default it will support erb. If you want you use `--template-framework` option to choose handlebars or mustache template framework.